# Hibernate boolean with Microsoft SQL Server tinyint

Tags: sql, hibernate

We have column `isSystem` as `tinyint` in Microsoft SQL Server. We mapped this column in hibernate as `boolean`.

**Hibernate** This is how I use where condition in Hibernate.

`/* We added restriction like this */
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("system", true));`

**Problem:** When I run code from hibernate Its not using database index but If I fire query as follow in Microsoft SQL Server directly then it uses index. How hibernate works around `TRUE` and `FALSE` with `tinyint` in SQL Server.

**Query:** `SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE isSystem = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this in entity

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "TINYINT")
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
public boolean isSystem;
```